# SvelteKit: Redirect in load() after checking if user is logged in with firebase

Tags: firebase, svelte, sveltekit

Inside my +layout.server.js I want to check if the user is logged in with firebase. If not (and they are not already on the login/sign-up page), I want to redirect them to the login page before the original page is displayed.

Therefore I use the onAuthStateChanged() function inside the load() function. So my files look like that:

**+layout.svelte:**

```
<script>
</script>
<slot></slot>
```

**+layout.server.js:**

```
export async function load({ url }) {
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
            //? Why do I never get here?
            console.log("Hello, you are logged in")
        }
        else {
            console.log("Not logged in!")
            console.log(url.pathname)
            if (!url.pathname.includes("login") && !url.pathname.includes("signup")) {
                console.log("Not on login/signup. To be redirected")
                //? How to redirect?
                // throw redirect(302, '/login'); --> Does not work
                // return {status: 302, redirect: "/login"}; --> Does not work
            }
            else {
                return
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1. It always goes into else (with console.log("Not logged in!)...), even when logged in
2. How can I redirect to the login page. I have tried several methods but none worked

---

What I tried, which actually worked perfectly fine, was in my **+layout.svelte** (without a +layout.server.js file):

```
<script>
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { goto } from "$app/navigation";
import { app } from "./initializeFirebase";
import { page } from "$app/stores";


onMount(() => {
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
            console.log("Hello")
        }
        else {
            if (page.pathname != "login" || page.pathname != "signup") {
                goto("/login")
            }
        }
    })
})

</script>
<slot></slot>
```

However, that first loads the content and then redirects to login, which is obviously not what I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Firebase but I believe this is a problem of asynchronicity. Basically, it looks to me like your code is returning before running the inner part of `onAuthStateChanged`.

I'd try to force SvelteKit to wait for it with a promise. For example:

```js
export async function load({ url }) {
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (user) {
                //? Why do I never get here?
                console.log("Hello, you are logged in")
            }
            else {
                console.log("Not logged in!")
                console.log(url.pathname)
                if (!url.pathname.includes("login") && !url.pathname.includes("signup")) {
                    console.log("Not on login/signup. To be redirected")
                    //? How to redirect?
                    // throw redirect(302, '/login'); --> Does not work
                    // resolve({status: 302, redirect: "/login"}); --> Does not work
                    // ^^^^^^^ I've also added it here
                }
                else {
                    resolve();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

By returning a promise like this, SvelteKit will wait until it completes before continuing the process.

To be clear, the problem (I think) it is not that the code is not being executed but, instead, that the codes does execute *after* the load function has completed while, what you want, is for it to execute *for* the load function to be completed.

Finally, I'm instantiating a new promise like this because I don't know the signature of the firebase function. If the firebase function happens to return a promise itself, you could very well return such promise directly instead.